# Catching secnd two Javascript Datetime picker values

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using [bootstrap-datetimepicker plugin from Jonathan Peterson](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) on my project.

There are two datetimepickers in the project. I can catch the first value with JavaScript. But the second datetimepicker value does not come
Javascript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnGetir").click(function () {
            var Datas = {
                besStartDate: $('#StartDate').on('dp.change', function (e) {
                    console.log(e.date);
                }).val(),
                besStopDate: $('#EndDate').on('dp.change', function (d) {
                    console.log(d.datetimepicker);
                }).val(),
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetSimulation", "Bes")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: Datas,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        })
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: In the first you are using `e.date` and the second you are using `d.datetimepicker`?  Maybe `d.date`?

Comment: not important. This time I can get the value of "besEndDate" while changing places. I can only get one value